# Instantiation of chained filters with or without service container

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I have different **Filter** classes and each class has a number of filter methods.
There is ( so far ) one case where I need to apply filters from 2 classes.
What I did is that I created another class named **FilterManager** which stores a list of all the **Filter** classes you need and then it iterates over the list and applies the filters.

```
class ThreadFilters 
{
    protected $builder;
    protected $supportedFilters = ['newThreads'];
    public function newThreads($userId)
    {
        $this->builder->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
    }
}
```

```
class FilterManager
{
    protected $filters = [];
    
    public function addFilter($filter)
    {
        $this->filters[] = $filter;
    }

    public function apply($builder)
    {
        foreach($this->filters as $filter)
        {
                $filter->builder = $builder;
                foreach($filter->supportedFilters as $filterMethod)
                {   
                    $filter->$filterMethod()
                }
                $builder = $filter->builder;
        }
    
    }
}
```

Now in the controller I can do something like

**First Approach**

```
class ThreadController(FilterManager $filterManager)
{
    $filters = $filterManager->addFilter(new ThreadFilter());
    $filters->apply($someBuilder);
}
```

On the other hand I could use the **app** function

```
app(ThreadFilters::class)
```

and in the service container basically I could do

```
$this->app->bind(ThreadFilters::class, function($app){
    $filterManager = new FilterManager();
    $filterManager->addFilter(new ThreadFilters());
    return $filterManager;
});
```

and therefore my controller would look like

**Second Approach**

```
class ThreadController()
{
    $filters = app(ThreadFilters::class);
    $filter->apply($someBuilder);
}
```

My question is which solution is good/acceptable.

In the **First Approach** the **FilterManager** dependency is injected and the controller has to add the **ThreadFilters**

In the **Second Approach** no dependencies are injected and the controller has to use the service container to hide the specifics and make the controller has less knowledge about the filters.

Comment: I don't find any practical difference. The controller is coupled with the ThreadFilters in both cases and (due to how Laravel works) adding or removing an injected parameter to the controller doesn't change things much

Comment: @apokryfos Yes indeed, you are right. Could you please rephrase the " adding or removing an injected parameter to the controller doesn't change things" because i didn't understand it .

Comment: If for example you have `function threadControllerRouteHandler(FilterManager $filterManager)` an this is called via dependency injection, then you can freely add and remove parameters without needing to make any changes anywhere else because all dependencies are injected. In that sense it doesn't matter if you inject them in the method body yourself or you let Laravel inject them when calling the method. The point is you won't break other code if you change the method signature (which is a concern when calling a method normally)

Comment: @apokryfos if I understand correctly, you are saying that it doesn't matter if I use dependency injection like ```function controller(FilterManager $filterManager)``` or I use the app() method to resolve my dependencies like  ```app(ThreadFilters::class)``` which eventually will return a **FilterManager**

Comment: In this case I don't find it to make a difference. Both use dependency injection. However I would suggest when you bind `ThreadFilters::class` to return a `ThreadFilters::class`. it's just confusing otherwise.

Comment: that Is one of my issues. because the ```ThreadFilters::class``` itself contains only the filter methods whereas the ```FilterManager::class``` is the class that stores/chains the **FilterClasses** and also applies the filters. Any suggestions are appreciated. If I give the responsibility to ```ThreadFilters::class``` to apply the filters, then I can't chain the filters, and in my case I have to use/chain ( so far ) at some point 2 different **FilterClasses**

Comment: Personally I'd just use a named binding e.g. `$this->app->bind('filters.thread', function ...)` and you can also add  others. Each of these can return a filter manager. The downside is you have to use `app('filters.thread')` to inject this as you can't inject it via a parameter. You can also use something like `app()->makeWith(FilterManager::class, [ 'parameter' => 'parameter value' ])` if you want a more contextual resolution